# Communicating between classes iOS NSObject and UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, communication, void-pointers, nsobject

I have two classes, a class1 which is an NSObject and a class2 which is a UIViewController...
From the UIViewController I sent something to class1 to get it to do an action:

```
[class1 doVoidAction];
```

and in class1 I have:

```
-(void)doVoidAction{ blah blah blah }
```

That worked fine... but after it's done doing the void action I need it to send something back to the view controller to do something over there now... So I tried the same method, including the .h files, saying @class class2; I did this whole deal:

```
@interface class1 : NSObject  {
    class2 *class2;
}
```

And in class2 I have in the .h file -(void)action2; and in the .m I have -(void)action2{ blah blah blah }

But for whatever reason they do not seem to want to communicate back that way! normally I would just hook up things int he xib file and do that but since class1 is an NSObject I can't use IBOutlet and hook up things in the xib file, to my knowledge at least.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your method to be something like:

```
-(void)doVoidActionFor:(UIViewController *)controller { blah blah blah }
```

You would call it as:

```
[class1 doVoidActionFor:self];
```

And the last 'blah' would be:

```
[controller action2];
```